# regional google cloud storage, where is my data?

Tags: storage, cloud, google

when using a regional google storage bucket what does it mean in terms of zones ?
for example if we choose europe-west3 as region (Frankfurt) for the bucket. Will the data be replicated to multiple zones (europe-west3-a, europe-west3-b etc.) and are those zones considered geographically separated within the city?

thanks in advance,
Noirabys

Answer (score 0):

Your data is where you set the location on your bucket.

Only you can decide in your DR planning what geographically separated means. Inter region zones are close by, but still physically independent. Other regions are far away. Same city versus different city.

GCP storage buckets are stored in [your choice of region](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations), and spread across close zones internally for redundancy. Multi-region locations tell GCP to replicate to another region as well.

Separate from object storage, [block storage has one zone only options](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks). Zonal persistent disks are faster, but you can only attach to an instance in one zone.